# jsf rendered condition not working with selectOneMenu

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

Hi I have read tons of similar questions but the answers didnt work for me.

I have this

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="tipoTaxon" value="#{taxonDM.taxon.tipoTaxon}"
                        name="tipoTaxon">
                        <f:converter converterId="tipoTaxonConverter" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione uno" itemValue="0" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{tipoTaxonDM.tiposTaxones}" var="txn"
                            itemValue="#{txn.idTipoTaxon}" itemLabel="#{txn.nombreTipo}" />
                        <p:ajax  render="test" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                    <p:inputText id="test" rendered="#{taxonDM.taxon.tipoTaxon != null}" />
```

As you can see I want to render test when an option is selected. tipoTaxon is basically a table on my database and is class, so I had to make a converter.  It seems to work so for now, I am not getting the errors I had before. Now I dont get any errors but "test" is not getting rendered.

I tried the following

```
#{taxonDM.taxon.tipoTaxon != null}
```

also

```
#{taxonDM.taxon.tipoTaxon.idTipoTaxon != null}"
```

I tried setting test on another panel

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" id="formTaxon">
                    <h:outputLabel value="Nombre Científico Taxón" for="taxonInput" />
                    <p:inputText value="#{taxonDM.taxon.nombreCientificoTaxon}"
                        id="taxonInput" />
                    <h:outputLabel value="Nombre Común" for="nombreComunInput" />
                    <p:inputText value="#{taxonDM.taxon.nombreComunTaxon}"
                        id="nombreComunInput" />
                    <h:outputLabel value="Tipo" for="tipoTaxon" />
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="tipoTaxon" value="#{taxonDM.taxon.tipoTaxon}"
                        name="tipoTaxon">
                        <f:converter converterId="tipoTaxonConverter" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione uno" itemValue="0" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{tipoTaxonDM.tiposTaxones}" var="txn"
                            itemValue="#{txn.idTipoTaxon}" itemLabel="#{txn.nombreTipo}" />
                        <p:ajax  render="formTaxon2" />

                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="formTaxon2">
                    <p:inputText id="test" rendered="#{taxonDM.taxon.tipoTaxon != null}" />
                </h:panelGrid>
```

using render="test" or render="formTaxon2"

I added a listener method to p:ajax and it worked so i know it is getting invoked.

```
    public void tipoTaxonesXX(AjaxBehaviorEvent e){
            System.out.println("Working");
    }
```

It did printed "Working" on my console. 
My form is not saving either so I guess it has trouble transforming from tipotaxon or number, but it gets null, i ll fix that later.

Here is the converter if someone needs to

```
import ec.edu.puce.biologia.model.TipoTaxon;

@FacesConverter("tipoTaxonConverter")
public class TipoTaxonConverter implements Converter {

    private TipoTaxonDao tipoTaxonDao;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(final FacesContext arg0, final UIComponent arg1,
            final String value) {
        if (value == null || !value.matches("\\d+")) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            TipoTaxon tipoTaxon = tipoTaxonDao.recuperar(Long.valueOf(value));
            System.out.println("Getting the operation value = "
                    + tipoTaxon.getNombreTipo());
            return tipoTaxon;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return null;
            // throw new ConverterException(new
            // FacesMessage("Unknown operation ID: " + value));
        } /*
         * catch (EntidadNoEncontradaException e) { throw new
         * ConverterException(new FacesMessage("Unknown operation ID: " +
         * value)); }
         */
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(final FacesContext arg0, final UIComponent arg1,
            final Object value) {
        if (!(value instanceof TipoTaxon)
                || ((TipoTaxon) value).getIdTipoTaxon() == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return String.valueOf(((TipoTaxon) value).getIdTipoTaxon());
    }
}
```

I need to put some exceptions

**UPDATE ANSWER**
My code here has many errors, I changed it a lot, but the main problem was that the EJB on the converter didnt work. I ended up using ManagedBean. More on that here http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ProcessingGETRequestParameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my [previous answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16306191/1820286), both `<p:selectOneMany>` value must point to your user class, `TipoTaxon`, **and** every `<f:selectItem>`/`<f:selectItems>` itemValue must also point that same user class, `TipoTaxon`.

As you see, neither `itemValue="0"`, nor `itemValue="txn.nombreTipo"` satisfies the abovementioned statement. Correct it and see it working.

---

My advice for future postings will be to post the *complete, relevant and **necessarily formatted** code*, which in your case includes converter code, your model class and managed bean parts. Also, do not post the *same* question twice/thrice, etc. and instead try *to work it out on your own*, otherwise it'll be closed as duplicate.

Comment: I appreciate the time you take to answer, but I am new to JSF not to stackoverflow, so I do my best to post in the most clear way with my code formatted. If for some reason my code is not formatted, could be do to some edit I did that it slipped away.  I felt like this was a different question. I am not saying any of this in a snarky way.  If you see the time difference in between each question is about 24hours, 24hours I have being stuck on the same thing, so I was trying anything and everything.  I read all I could find about converters.

Comment: Also I deleted f:selectItem and there was no change.

Comment: @JuanDiego I didn't mean to 'teach' you, but rather to give you a friendly piece of advice! We're all here to help each other and learn. So that comment was in no way intended to hurt your abilities to learn. Moreover, if you will explicitly specify what you don't understand up till now, I'll answer/explain that with pleasure. So, go on, ask :)

Comment: Why don't you handle dependency injection for your DAO inside converter?

Comment: thanks for everything.  What do you  mean with dependency injection, what do you suggest i do there.  Also if I use f:ajax with render I get java.lang.IllegalStateException.  I read that p:ajax has to go with update, but I get no error, just nothing happens.  If it is not to much to ask how would you have handle this, I am kind of asking a rewrite of my code, sorry if it is to much. But I feel my approach is all wrong.

Comment: TaxonController is viewscoped and so is TaxonDM, should it be sessionscoped?

Comment: I know what is happening, my converter is always returning null.

Comment: It should be corrected by placing a proper annotation on your DAO in converter, making the converter itself `@ManagedBean` and referring to it in tags not by `<f:converter>`, but by `converter="#{yourConverter}"` attribute. Wait for a full working example to examine.

Comment: You mean I should change the @FacesConverter to @ManagedBean?

Comment: LoL I just read this that you answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15392887/use-managedbean-in-facesconverter